# When displayed in a 1000 x 1000 window, why would a 1000 x 1000 image look more pixelated than a 500 x 500 image?

Tags: graphics, algorithm

Yes, you read that correctly.  I am especially concerned about the white pixels bordering the black curves.  As you see, I have increased the line width 2-fold in the higher resolution image.

This code produces 2 images, and the only difference is AbsoluteThickness = 3 or 6 and ImageSize = 500 or 1000, respectively, both in gray text background.

```
is = 500;  (* Image Size *)
at = 3;
MatrixPlot[
 MorphologicalComponents[
  Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[at], 
    BezierCurve[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}]], SplineClosed -> True, 
    SplineDegree -> RandomInteger[{4, 16}]}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> {is, is}]], 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> Black, 1 -> Red, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Blue, 
   4 -> Cyan, 5 -> Magenta, 6 -> Yellow, 7 -> Brown, 8 -> Orange, 
   9 -> Pink}, ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}] 


is = 1000;  (* Image Size *)
at = 6;
MatrixPlot[
 MorphologicalComponents[
  Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[at], 
    BezierCurve[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}]], SplineClosed -> True, 
    SplineDegree -> RandomInteger[{4, 16}]}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> {is, is}]], 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> Black, 1 -> Red, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Blue, 
   4 -> Cyan, 5 -> Magenta, 6 -> Yellow, 7 -> Brown, 8 -> Orange, 
   9 -> Pink}, ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}]
```

Comment: Very interesting—I'll note to whoever else is looking at this that this does not appear to be a scaling effect due to the outer `ImageSize`, as lowering it to `{500, 500}` maintains the pixelated look and extraneous white outlines in (only) the second case.

Comment: This also seems to be a problem with `MatrixPlot` in particular, as "zooming in" to the second one, with e.g. `[[1;;500, 1;;500]]` and then plotting it avoids the pixelated/white outline effect.

Comment: While it still might be useful to find a workaround, personally, I'd call this a bug. Might be worth contacting [wolfram support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback) and seeing what they think.

Comment: In any case, you can force Mathematica to avoid this behavior by setting `MaxPlotPoints -> 2*is` inside `MatrixPlot`; not sure this answers your question as to "why", though.

Comment: @thorimur - In the high res 1000 x 1000 image, MaxPlotPoints -> 1000 is as bad as no option, and MaxPlotPoints -> 2000 is a fix!

Comment: right! I think it might have to do with plotting all of the matrix elements, since that matrix is `2000` by `2000`, and here `2000` is equal to `2*is`